# Reading from a textfile to blacklist urls

Tags: c#

So I'm writing an IRC bot that in theory would read from blacklist.txt and if it matches it should ban the user. However I'm having problems parsing the text the user outputs.

Say in the blacklist I have:

1. http://youtube.com
2. www.google.com

When I type: http://google.com/ it should read the blacklist and return my ban message but it only reads it as a sensative thing so if my text does not contain "www.google.com" it complete ignores it.

Here's my bool for detection.

```
    public static bool isUrlBlacklisted(String value)
    {
        string[] url = File.ReadAllText("blacklist.txt")
            .Split().Where(x => x.Contains(value))
            .Distinct().ToArray();
        return url.Contains(value);
    }
```

Comment: I think it's normal since "www.google.com" != "http://google.com"

Comment: You should just add google to your file.

Comment: why not just remove the http:// or www. and only compare "google.com" or "whatever.org"? either in the file or in code if you don't have control of the file contents

Comment: I tried that, then it doesn't pick up anything. irc.DataMessage.Replace("http:", "").Replace("/", "");

Comment: After you've replaced all those portions, can you dump both `value` and the contents of the `url` array so we can see what they each contain?

Comment: So, it returns what I wish it would, replacing http:// and removing // as well as 'www' but, now I have another issue with it. ---- <trub0t> URL Return: youtube.comq?=stuff , now I need to just get the url out of an entire URI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
string[] url = File.ReadAllText("blacklist.txt")
        .Split();
Array.Exists(url, x => x.Contains(value));
```

Comment: No overload for method 'Exists' takes 1 argument.

Comment: Fixed my answer. Sorry :)

Comment: So I've tried it, and the problem is it still only accepts one answer. On my blacklist I have 'youtube.com', when I go into chat and type youtube.com it works, but if I add http:// or any variant it won't pick up.